# Python do not recognize variable under a for loop

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to loop through 20 newsgroup dataset, at the end i join all the files under a variable called file_path. However, i am getting the following error at the next line :

> name 'file_path' is not defined

```
import os
for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk(my_directory):
    for special_file in files:
        if special_file.endswith(''):
            file_path = os.path.join(root, special_file)
```

What is my mistake? clearly i have defined file_path correctly.

Comment: most likely because the loop is never reaching `file_path = os.path.join(root, special_file` (is `if special_file.endswith(''):` your actual condition? That is *always* true for all strings).

Comment: I removed the not necessary loop but still the file_path is not recognized,                                        for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk(my_directory):
    file_path = os.path.join(root, files)

Comment: what my_directory is assigned to and can you print full error message from console?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Its the directory path, which was not correctly written. The code now runs.

Answer (score 1):

Using variables which are exclusively declared in a conditional statement is bad design. Define either a default `file_path` as fallback or don't use it outside of the conditional statement where it's defined.